# Android - display DICOM image with PixelMed Java DICOM Toolkit

Tags: android, dicom, dcm4che, pixelmed

Do you know how can I display a DICOM image using [PixelMed™ Java DICOM Toolkit](http://www.pixelmed.com) on Android? If it is not possible which library should I use to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would give imebra a try.  They have a youtube demo project which shows it in action and it looks good. I also downloaded the source to take a peak at the documentation and it looks fairly straight forward.

http://imebra.com/

Comment: Try searching internet for DICOM Android SDK and you should find some open source as well as commercial SDKs